# Can I perform Umrah while on a Saudi Arabian visit e-visa?

Tags: visas, saudi-arabia, islam, pilgrimages

For those who don't know, just a few days ago Saudi Arabia, known for being inaccessible, introduced a new e-visa system for a handful of countries, which include the whole Schengen area, the U.S and Australia, so whoever wants to visit it can do so with no struggle.

With regards to the question, it was not specific whether I can perform [Umrah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umrah) or not with that kind of visa, so can one perform umrah with it?

Comment: Is there an official link to this?

Comment: Yes, just google it and you'll find

Comment: The evisa has been covered in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143117/how-does-one-get-a-visa-to-go-to-saudi-arabia and at least one other question, although given the specific question here this is not a dup as such

Comment: The e-visa was made available only a few days ago, hence my question is about an issue occurred very recently, not 2 months ago, even if it's about the same topic.

Comment: @abdul: If you expect other people to take time to answer your question, you could take 30s to add a link to Wikipedia to explain what Umrah is. Here it is, by the way: ["an Islamic pilgrimage to Mecca that can be undertaken at any time of the year"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umrah).

Comment: Yeah sorry, since I frequent Islamic pages a lot, I assumed you already knew it by default.

Comment: @abdul: But then SergeyA asked for a link, and you told him to google it. Just like you could google if it's possible to perform Umrah with an eVisa.

Comment: @EricDuminil in context of travel to Saudi Arabia, "Umrah" is as common a concept as "Christmas" is we were talking about the US. Do we need to link to Wikipedia for the latter too?

Comment: @dbkk the context was also Hot Network Questions. Many people came here who had no clue about Saudi Arabia.

Answer (score 40):

Yes, you can perform Umrah while on a visit eVisa.

From the official [eVisa website](https://visa.visitsaudi.com/Home/TermsConditions):

> 8.7 An eVisa is granted solely for tourist purposes **or for the purpose of performing a umrah** and it is not considered a visa for work. If you are granted an eVisa, you must not take up paid employment during your visit to KSA.

Comment: Would it also allow doing a Hajj?

Comment: @JonathanReez Hajj is subject to quota and other things, I do not think it will be allowed.

Comment: I could bypass the thing by pretending to vacation in Jeddah

Comment: @abdul and risk making a tiny place more crowded? or getting caught and deported? just do it officially.

Comment: How is It illegal to station in Jeddah and perforn Umrah in Makkah, which happens to be only 50 or maybe 100 km from Makkah? Many people do this every year.

Comment: @abdul I thought you're talking about Hajj

Comment: Well they're not the same, Hajj does have quotas but only for certain crowded and Muslim countries like Pakistan, Egypt, Bangladesh, Morocco and Algeria. I don't know whether there are quotas for western countries, but if there are any, they are laughibly irrelevantly stringent, because of the lack of Muslims in Western countries like, let's say, France or Belgium. Consider that a Hajj visa is granted to 1/1000 chance in Pakistan, since literally everyone dreams to perform it.

Comment: @abdul to perform hajj you must have either a hajj visa, or a permission. Even saudis must have a permission or they will face a serious fine. The quota is for safety, the place is tiny and squeezing 3 million people in it is difficult, having people come with no plan is the last thing the authorities want. Just remember, 1.3 billion muslims who are required to do it once in their lifetime, allowing people to perform it as they wish is really a bad decision. Currently it is allowed to do it once every 5 years. Regarding EU quota it depends on the muslim population in any given country.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can perform Umrah on a Saudi Arabian e-visa.

From [this news article](http://saudigazette.com.sa/article/578574):

> **Among the most important features of the Saudi tourist visa, is the visa holder can benefit from it in performing Umrah**, women need not be accompanied by a male relative, other than in the Haj season, and there is no need for a sponsor (kafeel) the way it is required for work visas.
>
> [...]
>
> They can get their visas manually via the Kingdom’s representative offices abroad (embassies, consulates, etc.) a**nd electronically without preconditions for 49 nationalities**, including Europe, Asia and America.

Also backed up by another news article [here](https://www.hoteliermiddleeast.com/business/109221-you-can-now-perform-umrah-on-a-saudi-tourist-visa).